# Created in test setup objects can not be accessed through database

Tags: django, database, testing

I got a

```
 class TestReportModel(TestCase):

   @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.report_id = 99
        cls.factory = RequestFactory()
        cls.user = User.objects.create(username="user1", password="password")
        cls.report = Report.objects.create()
```

which initializes objects i need in

```
 def test_report_employee_with_access(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/reports/{}'.format(self.report_id))
        report = self.report
        report.user = request.user
        request.user = self.user
        response = report(request, self.report_id)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

In the view report

```
@login_required()
def report(request, report_id):
    a = Report.objects.get(id = report_id)
```

I can get my User with User.object.get(id = user_id). According to my model User doesn't know anything about Report. That's why I cant get report like user.report. I can only create a db query like Report.object.get(id=report_id) but i get an empty queryset. How can I fix it?

Comment: Just to rule out my answer, did you actually call the `super` method inside your `setUpClass` method?

Comment: no, could u please explain?

Comment: Did you read the warning in my answer, or follow the link to the doc?  In the doc, there is an example of how to override `setUpClass` properly.

Comment: Without more information (e.g., a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I can only offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but could cause some issues.  In my TestCase classes, I generally define `setUp()`, but not `setUpClass`.  If you do, make sure you call the `super` method.  From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase):

> Warning
>
> SimpleTestCase and its subclasses (e.g. TestCase, …) rely on
>   setUpClass() and tearDownClass() to perform some class-wide
>   initialization (e.g. overriding settings). If you need to override
>   those methods, don’t forget to call the super implementation

The `SimpleTestClass.setUpClass` method is responsible for setting up database connection, so if it's not called first, you won't be hitting the test database.

Comment: I use objects created in setUpClass more than one time. If I use setUp it will cause database issues because it will try to create all the objects again.

Comment: I try to avoid that myself because then weird test issues can come up if the tests run in unexpected order (e.g., re-used model objects that have changed in one of the tests), but I guess this doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: Seems like django creates a temporary db where all that objects are stored. And I can't access them through my main db.

Comment: You didn't say you were trying to access them through the main db.  If you use a query like `User.objects.get()` in your test case, you are querying the temporary db.